# What are the best BizTalk 2010 books?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_1_12?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=biztalk+2010&x=0&y=0&sprefix=biztalk+2010

I'm trying to come up to speed on BizTalk 2010.  I've been a .NET Web Developer for almost 10 years.  I have some experience with SQL Server Integration Services however BizTalk is a world of different.

Please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right that BizTalk is quite different, though both .NET development and SQL experience will be helpful.

Since [Microsoft's list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/dd807027) is a bit out of date, here is my short list of BizTalk books (with Amazon affiliate links):

- **[BizTalk Server 2010 Unleashed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672331187)** - Introductory, developer-centric, covers all the bases
- **[Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010 Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/184968460X)** - A more in-depth intro to BizTalk that covers the "why" with patterns and explanations, followed by a number of real-world solutions
- **[SOA Patterns with BizTalk Server 2009](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847195008)** - Yes it's an older version, but this is still the book to take you deepest into solving problems the right way with BizTalk

After you've figured out the what, how, and why, then there are additional resources to take you deeper into the specific realms of BizTalk that you might want to use:

- [Line of Business Systems Integration](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005I4JFTA)
- [Pro BAM in BizTalk Server 2009](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430219149) (Business Activity Monitoring didn't change much between '09 & '10)
- [Pro Mapping in BizTalk Server 2009](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430218576) (The mapper changed drastically in 2010—for the better—but the complex mappings covered in this book largely still apply

Comment: There is a new version of the SOA Patterns book called, SOA Patterns with BizTalk Server 2013 and Microsoft Azure - Second Edition https://www.packtpub.com/networking-and-servers/soa-patterns-biztalk-server-2013-second-edition  (Full disclosure: I am a co-author on this version)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read one book to understand about BizTalk then I'll recommend "Professional BizTalk Server 2006" authored by Darren Jefford , Kevin B. Smith , Ewan Fairweather http://www.amazon.co.uk/Professional-BizTalk-Server-Darren-Jefford/dp/0470046422

It says 2006, but the concepts are still the same from 2004 to 2010 R2